# uploading a realtime database into the web

Tags: database, ms-access, upload

Hi everyone I hav a small problem in uploading my database. I have created a localhost website on my pc for a vehicle tracking system and now i have no clue in uploading it. It's got two Microsoft Access databases in my pc which is used in the website and they get updated at very regular intervals(almost every second) it has to be uploaded to the web real time. Right now I use ODBC on a localhost..
Does anybody have any idea how to do it?
Please help if so...

Comment: What do you mean by "uploaded to the web?"  Are you talking about presenting the data realtime on localhost?  Or are you talking about uploading your site to a publicly accessible host?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your traffic using ACCESS in a webserver multi user environment will be a real pain. (File in access, etc). Perhaps try to build a webservice to make changes directly on the server?

If you don't want to use ODBC you may have a look at ADO connectionstrings (www.connectionstrings.com is a goot starting point).

Answer (score 1):

I would concur with @Sascha I wouldnt even bother wasting the time trying to run your site with access.

Depending on your host you should have access to a free mysql or mssql database.  Use this instead.  Write a new page that takes parameters and writes them to your online database, that way you can set up a relay on your machine that pushes the changes from your local machine to the web.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not easy, but it can be done.  You would need to run a SQL Server database on the web server, and then push the data from Access to SQL Server, or pull it from SQL Server.

We've got a couple of links talking about it at SQLServerPedia:

- [How can I synchronize data between MS Access and SQL Server databases?](http://web.archive.org/web/20100207052632/http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/2007/08/page/im-a-newbie/how-can-i-synchronize-data-between-ms-access-and-sql-server-databases/)
- [How can I link a SQL Server database to MS Access using link tables in MS Access?](http://web.archive.org/web/20130122041144/http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/replication/how-can-i-link-a-sql-server-database-to-ms-access-using-link-tables-in-ms-access/)

Again, it's not easy - judging by the way you worded the question, you're not going to like the answers that you'll read about.  You may want to bring in someone who's experienced with web-based databases and replication in order to bring you up to speed and set your expectations about how challenging this will be.